# iOS / Swift: Imported .framework is incomplete or showing wrong classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is a really odd problem so I will try to explain the best I can. I have a .framework which I added to my project as an "Embedded Binary" in Xcode:

[image]

Then I import it in my Controller like this:

```
import FrameworkName
```

This works fine when I import it in a new project. I can access all it's classes and functions. For some reason, when I import it in an existing project I'm working on, it only shows the first 16 lines of code in the header file and I cannot access any of the functions in it. Is there any configuration in Xcode that might be blocking this .framework?

I hope this question made sense. Please let me know if you need me to post anything else regarding my project. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does deleting the project's derived data do anything?

Comment: Tried it. No luck :/ I don't understand it works in any new project I create but for some reason it does not work in this particular project.

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Are you using a stable version of Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it appears that the answers is pretty simple. The FrameworkName.framework has to be named differently that your project.

For example: if the app is named StackOverflow and you try to import a StackOverflow.framework, your project is going to ignore the later. I had to go back to the framework's project and rename the entire thing in order for it to work. Vice versa should work also.